# Find $f(1)$ and also find monotonicity of $f(x)$ and $f\left(f(x)\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> > Consider $\alpha>1$ and $f:\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}, \alpha\right]\to\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}, \alpha\right]$ be a bijective function. Suppose that $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1}{f(x)}$ for all $x\in \left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}, \alpha\right]$. Then find $f(1)$ and also find monotonicity of $f(x)$ and $f\left(f(x)\right)$

**Given solution in Book for $f(1)$:** Author of book replaced $x$ by $f(x)$ in given equation and then he obtained $x=\dfrac{1}{f\left(f(x)\right)}\implies f(f(x))=\dfrac{1}{x}$  $\implies f^{-1}(x)=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right).......(1)$ and from $(1)$ and given equation in question he obtained $f(x)f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=1$

Now set $x=1$ and he obtained $f(1)=1$

**Doubts:**

(1) As I studied in my classroom that when $f(x)$ is increasing then $f^{-1}(x)$ will be increasing but according to given function in question as $f(x)$ increases $f^{-1}(x)$ decreases. So it is possible for continuous or discontinuous function.

(2) How to obtain the proof of monotonicity of $f(x)$ and $f(f(x))$?

Comment: For a bijection between intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, there *is* equivalence between monotonicity and continuity, but all that means is that the $f$ present here is necessarily discontinuous and not monotonic.

Comment: On the other hand $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}$ is monotonic

Answer (score 3):

For $x_1,x_2\in\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}, \alpha\right]$ with $x_1<x_2$. Then $\frac1{x_1}>\frac1{x_2}$ and hence
$$ f\left(\dfrac{1}{x_1}\right)>f\left(\dfrac{1}{x_2}\right) $$
since $f(x)$ is increasing. So
$$ f^{-1}(x_1)-f^{-1}(x_2)=\dfrac{1}{f(x_1)}-\dfrac{1}{f(x_2)}<0 $$
which means that $f^{-1}(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: $f$ is not assumed to be increasing, and the conclusion you should have here is that $f^{-1}$ would be decreasing when $f$ is increasing here. You have the wrong sign on that last equation.

Comment: $f$ is strictly increasing if $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ for any $x_1<x_2$ in the domain.

Comment: You should have $$x_1 < x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) < f(x_2) \Rightarrow 1/f(x_1) > 1/f(x_2)$$ But again, it doesn't really matter because $f$ is nowhere assumed to be increasing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) can be answered at the same time: finding the monotonicity of $f$ (and not $f(x)$, $f(x)$ is a number, $f$ is the function) usually does not mean that $f$ *is* monotonic but rather the question wants you to see *whether* it is monotonic or not. Not always though, since it's a bit ambiguous admittedly, so it wouldn't hurt for the asker (not referring to you OP!) to add "finding monotonicity or non-monotonicity" even if it can feel a bit uglier.

You are right that in your case $f^{-1}$ would be increasing whenever $f$ is decreasing and vice versa, while generally they should have the same monotonicity, but there is no contradiction:
What you've seen is that, for this specific $f$:
$$\begin{cases} x \leq y \\ f(x) \leq f(y) \end{cases} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad f^{-1}(x) \leq f^{-1}(y)$$
whereas for some bijective function $g$:
$$\left(\forall x \leq y,\, g(x) \leq g(y)\right) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left(\forall u \leq v,\, g^{-1}(u) \leq g^{-1}(v)\right)$$
The distinction lies in the fact that, for a generic bijection $g$, you cannot say that for a given $(x,y)$, $g(x) \leq g(y)$ implies that $x \leq y$, for example consider the following function:
$$g : x \in [-1, 1] \mapsto \begin{cases}  1 + x \quad\text{if } -1 < x < 0 \\ x - 1 \quad\text{if } 0 < x < 1\\ x \quad\text{if } x \in \{0, -1, 1\}\end{cases}$$
where the third case was just to have the closed intervals on both ends for the domain and codomain, they don't have a specific role.
For that $g$, if we take $g(x) \leq g(y)$, then it's clear we can have both situations $x \leq y$ ($x$ and $y$ in the same subinterval) or $x \geq y$ (different subintervals).

What your findings do mean however is that $f$ *cannot* be monotonic on any subinterval of $\left[\frac1\alpha, \alpha\right]$, exactly for the reason above: $f^{-1}$ would then be increasing and decreasing hence constant, which is absurd for a bijection. Therefore $f$ is somewhat highly irregular, but that doesn't imply $f$ doesn't exist.

To conclude, $(f \circ f)(x) = \frac1x$ (as you pointed out as well as a comment) over positive reals thus it is decreasing.

Hopefully that helped, and hopefully I didn't mix things up myself. But in the latter case I'll be happy to receive any criticisms.